# Overlapping Lines on WPF canvas blending colors - how to fix?

Tags: wpf, canvas, colors

If I draw a line (assume **ls** is just a line segment with some coordinates) . . .

```
Line line = new Line();
String rgb = "#FF0000";  // Red
line.Stroke = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(rgb));
ls = PlyList[p].L3Ds[seg];
line.X1 = ls.P0.X;
line.Y1 = ls.P0.Y;
line.X2 = ls.P1.X;
line.Y2 = ls.P1.Y;
GeometryCnv.Children.Add(line);
```

... I get a red line.   If I do . . .

```
Line line = new Line();
String rgb = "#00FF00";  // Green
line.Stroke = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(rgb));
ls = PlyList[p].L3Ds[seg];
line.X1 = ls.P0.X;
line.Y1 = ls.P0.Y;
line.X2 = ls.P1.X;
line.Y2 = ls.P1.Y;
GeometryCnv.Children.Add(line);
```

... I get a green line.
But If I do both (using the same coordinates), I get a brownish-orange color as though the colors of the two lines were blended, as though the lines had some sort of transparency.    What I want to happen is for the most recent line to draw over the previous one so that the resulting color is the most recent color -  green in this case.

What do I need to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `SnapsToDevicePixels` to true on `GeometryCnv.` Aliasing from both lines is leading to the effect you're seeing.

Comment: Good call, that did it!